# SP2013: ResultScriptWebPart shows top 7 documents, but not the most viewed items, how to do?

Tags: 2013, search-results

I have a webpart on my home page. It shows a top 7 of documents. I see in the settings a checkbox checked with the title "Show Ranked results". But my target is to show a top 7 with the most viewed documents. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This link might help. Please try http://en.share-gate.com/blog/new-sharepoint-2013-analytics

Comment: Please do not just put links as answer, instead copy the main contents within the answer to keep it safe here. Links may die in future but SharePoint SE is immortal. :P

Comment: Thanks Keerthi for your fast support. I try to change the search query of this webpart. I added this sorting: sort by the field "ViewLifeTime" Descending. But the results are the same. Before it was sorting on Ranking.